# Laravel Passport protect multi auth (Guard) api routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I am Trying to implement multi auth api in laravel but couldn't protect the api routes. I tried almost every resources available online but failed to achieve my goal. I have used three guards for api authentication user, partner and admin. I am using the following guards

```
        'user-api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'partner-api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'partners',
        ],
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
```

and my api routes are

```
// User routes
Route::group(["middleware" => 'auth:user-api'], function () {
    Route::get("/usertest", function(){

        return "User Test Successful";

    });
});

// Partner Routes
Route::group(["middleware" => 'auth:partner-api'], function () {
     
     Route::get("/partnertest", function(){

         return "Partner Test Successful";
     
     });

});

// Admin Routes
Route::group(["middleware" => 'auth:admin-api'], function () {
     
     Route::get("/admintest", function(){
         
        return "Admin Test Successful";

     });

});
```

The Problems are

Using **User Token**:

Now whenever I test using user token it works fine user can access only his own routes not other routes.

Using **Partner Token**:

with partner token I can access both partner routes and admin routes.

Using **Admin Token**:

with admin token I can access both admin and partner routes

I just want each type of user can access their own routes not others routes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to just add a [token ability](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#token-abilities) to define the access?

Comment: I am using laravel passport. tried scope in passport from many articles but failed.

Comment: Well, couldn't gates or policies be a solution instead? Seems like you're overcomplicating a solution.